# Automatically boot instance with file containing data in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a webapp that allows you to submit a data file, then automatically splits that data file into `n` smaller files, boots up `n` EC2 instances, analyzes the data on each instance and then sends the results back to the central server. I see that you can 1) create an AMI with software already installed and 2)send EC2 instances a user-data script with some commands to run on boot, but I'm wondering how to get my actual data file onto the server. These files are all around and under 1 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but to me the most obvious would be to do the following:

1. Create an S3 bucket to hold the files
2. Upload the n files to the bucket
3. Start the instances and give them an IAM role with access to read the files from the bucket.

The userdata on your script could download the files from the bucket and kick off the processing.